# How to count the elements from a class with VBA + SELENIUM in chrome?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, trello

I want to count the numbers of elements aiming to get all their names and store in an array.

The names are highlighted [in this image](https://scontent.fsdu13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/61122554_682250658872476_6843501482428334080_n.png?_nc_cat=109&_nc_ht=scontent.fsdu13-1.fna&oh=37ea0526f170682388baaff66288a598&oe=5D58ECE8)

The names are store in "js-list list-wrapper" [as shown in image](https://scontent.fsdu13-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/60960847_757107631350048_3464949120697892864_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ht=scontent.fsdu13-1.fna&oh=a47a71e759358905afddf1640fdd2409&oe=5D55004A)

My code:

```
  Public Sub seleniumtutorial()
  Dim bot As New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
  Dim a As WebElement
  Dim b As WebElement
  Dim x() As Integer

  bot.Start "chrome", "https://trello.com/login"
  bot.get "/"

  bot.Type "name=user", "biaverly@id.uff.br"
  bot.Type "name=password", "xxxxxxx"
  bot.clickAndWait "id=login"
  bot.findElementByLinkText("Gestão de Pessoas").Click
```

I tried:

```
  Set a = bot.findElementsByClassName("board-canvas", 5).Count
```

and find elements by xpath,and id.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of html. Use the snippet tool via edit.

Comment: I'm new here, they don't let me do this yet. :\ I tried

Comment: Oh really? You can use snippet tool? If you use pastebin.com I can edit it in for you from link you share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the xpath from a random element in the class "js-list list-wrapper" and it was: 
//*[@id="board"]/div[5].

So i solved it using

```
 Dim titles As Object
 Set titles = 
 bot.findElementsByXPath("//[@id=""board""]/div")
 Dim ab As Long
 ab = titles.Count
 MsgBox ab
```

Answer (score 3):

Caveat: The below is for selenium basic vba. This uses the Selenium type library and is based on @florentbr's development from [here](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic). The syntax you are using makes me think the question potentially is wrongly tagged as the syntax, for the most part, is for [selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands/). Not sure if you are converting a script? I don't recall VBA being a supported language for the IDE but......

---

Trello headers will be class name `list-header-name`.

I would use faster `.FindElementsByCss`

So,

```
bot.FindElementsByCss(".list-header-name")
```

The "." before `list-header-name` is a css [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Modern browsers are optimized for this.

---

The `,5` is the value for the `minimum` argument; as you haven't used named arguments, matching will be positional. The third argument would be `timeout`. Both `minimum` and `timeout` are optional.

---

Now, when using `Set` keyword this is for assigning to an object variable:

```
Dim titles As Object
Set titles = bot.FindElementsByCss(".list-header-name")
```

You do not attempt to retrieve a property at the same time. Attempting:

```
Set titles = bot.FindElementsByCss(".list-header-name").Count
```

should lead to a **type mismatch** error.

You can separately take the webElement count from the collection with

```
Dim numberOfWebElements As Long
numberOfWebElements = titles.Count
```

---

For trello there are ids you can use for login. I would use those and SendKeys method

---

**Outline example:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SeleniumTutorial()
    Dim bot As WebDriver, titles As Object, i As Long
    Dim numberOfWebElements As Long, names(), t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set bot = New ChromeDriver

    With bot
        .get "https://trello.com/login"
        .Window.Maximize
        .FindElementById("user").SendKeys "userName"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "passWord"
        .FindElementById("login").Click
        .FindElementByLinkText("Gestão de Pessoas", timeout:=5000).Click  '< named argument

        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set titles = bot.FindElementsByCss(".list-header-name")
            numberOfWebElements = titles.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While numberOfWebElements = 0

        If numberOfWebElements = 0 Then Exit Sub

        ReDim names(1 To numberOfWebElements)

        For i = 1 To titles.Count
            names(i) = titles.item(i).Text
        Next

        Stop 'delete me later

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining the second parameter.  In my work, I don't use explicit waits. I throw it into a loop to keep trying until it succeeds, I press a key to stop, or an arbitrary number of iterations has completed and I am prompted to quit or continue trying.

Comment: Whatever works for you :-)  I prefer to find which ever method offers me the earliest exit though that is not always easy/possible(at least in my experience) to find.

Comment: Don't use that. See my answer above.

Comment: If i use `Set titles = bot.FindElementsByCss(".list-header-name").Count` shows the message **object doesn't support this property or method** else if i use the hole code of do, titles is empty so  numberOfWebElements = 0.

Comment: Step through with F8 -  my code uses a loop for up to 10 seconds to allow for trello board titles to be present. The sub should exit  If numberOfWebElements = 0. Are you using code exactly as is above but with your credentials?

Answer (score 1):

`findElementsByClassName` is definitely what you want but your usage doesn't look right. I am pretty sure `.count` returns a long, not a web element or an array of web elements.  I am also pretty sure it doesn't take a second parameter, what are you trying to accomplish with `, 5` and what was your error message?

To get the count of elements in that class

```
Dim classCount as Long
classCount = bot.findElementsByClassName("board-canvas").Count
```

Referring to the last element in that class

```
bot.findElementsByClassName("board-canvas").Item(classCount)
```

The contents of the last element in that class

```
bot.findElementsByClassName("board-canvas").Item(classCount).Text
```

Now, unfortunately, this is where I may stray a little off course because I don't have my work available for reference, but I believe you can retrieve the collection and loop through the class like this

```
Dim classTxt as String
Set a = bot.findElementsByClassName("board-canvas")
For each b in a
classTxt = b.Text
Next b
```