# Excel v.16 VBA SeleniumBasic array.length equivalent in Selenium

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, selenium

I have an array, and it used to work just fine in VBA. I am now using SeleniumBasic and am trying to find the equivalent of the command ".length"

```
    Dim i As Object        

    Dim elmCollection As Object

    Set elmCollection = WDrv.FindElementsByTag("table")
    
    For i = 0 To (elmCollection.Length)
```

It bombs out on the "For" statement. So, is there an equivalent to the ".length" in SeleniumBasic?

Comment: "bombs out" is not a very useful description of the error you get...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229812/how-to-count-the-elements-from-a-class-with-vba-selenium-in-chrome

Comment: Well, "bombs out" means that it just stops running when it hits that statement. There is no error message; I wish there was one. Also, I read the link you provided before i added my post. I had a hard time following it and I am not sure if it really applies to my question. I will study it some more.

Comment: `elmCollection.Count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual basic it's `ubound(array)` to get the upper boundary of an array.

You'll want to use:

```
For i = 0 To ubound(elmCollection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium basic `WebElements` collections IIRC start at 1 and the appropriate property is `.Count`. You are not working with an array.

Therefore your loop should in fact be a `For Each`,  e.g.

`Dim i As Object: For Each i In elmCollection`

to enumerate through the `WebElements` collection; if using the slower method of enumeration with objects then you want `For i = 1 to elmCollection.Count`